# Как найти js файл в котором приписаны стили для определенного елемента.которые отображаються как element.style

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

нужна ваша помощь. у меня есть слайдер у которого прописана зависимость transform в каком-то js файле. в консоли отображаеться как element.style.найти его не смог.есть какие нибудь способы найти етот файл? через консоль разработчика?)

Comment: Ищите папку в нод модулес или откуда вы его подключаете с вашим слайдером и смотрите исходники

Comment: а может переопределить в собственном css нежели искать что то где то